# jQuery removeClass() removes only one match

Tags: jquery

Here's the issue. For some unknown reason, this javascript function only removes the highlight on the first item with class ".folder", and doesn't remove it from the rest whenever a different one is clicked. I can't find anything possibly wrong with the code, yet it doesn't work. The jQuery API documentation states it should affect each element that matches the pattern.

What gives?

```
function init_ui(){
    // (some other functions omitted)
    $('.folder').click(function(){
        $('.folder').children().eq(0).removeClass('highlighted');
        $(this).children().eq(0).addClass('highlighted');
        $(init_ui);
    });
}
$(init_ui);
```

## Solution:

Simply remove .eq(0), as that means it will only match the first element of them all.

Comment: Rather than editing the question to include the answer, you should "accept" the answer that solved your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @IMSoP I know that very well. But the system will not allow to accept an answer too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.eq(0)` in there. That means you want "one element within that set" (from [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)). Specifically, the element in position zero, i.e. the first one that matches. If you don't want to limit the selection to one element, don't use `.eq()`.

Comment: Duh. My bad. I've always thought it's to get the first match of the children() function. Rookie mistake :P